Time Series Analysis without Forecasting
I have a dataset consisting of daily comments in a social media platform from 1999 to 2024.
The comments are categorized into two variables: X and Y.
The X variable is also categorized into 5 sub-categories: 1-2-3-4-5.
I hypothesize that the number of X became prevelant over Y in time. They both increased in numbers but X had a higher trend upwards. (it was visible from the graph)
Also, I hypothesize that the increase of the category 5 compared to other categories (1-2-3-4) is significant.
How should I test these statistically? I am really confused about differencing between stationary/non-stationary as I don't see why I would need to, for example, detrend this data to conduct tests.
Could you please assist me on how should I approach to finding correlations in this context?
